# amp-autocomplete: how to submit form after option selected?

Tags: amp-html

I'm learning about amp-autocomplete component at https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-autocomplete/

At the end of the page there's a note about events, but no code example.

The user should **select one** of the amp-autocomplete options and **automatically trigger the form submission**.

I've been trying like this:

```
<form>
...
<amp-autocomplete on="select:search-submit"> // How to trigger the submit event?

<template type="amp-mustache" id="search-template" class="search-template">
  <div class="search-item" data-value="{{title}}">
    <div>{{title}}</div>
   </div>
</template>

<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="Search" class="btn">

</amp-autocomplete>
</form>
```

But the form is not being submitted.

Comment: are you running all relevant libraries? it's very hard to guess what's happening - if you want help, you need to show all of your code.

Comment: Hey @JayGray! I wanted the user to select one of the amp-autocomplete options and to automatically trigger the form submission. I'm not sure if all the code is relevant, I wanted to know if anyone have a working example of this case. I'll update the post with more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your code

1. `<form>` => `<form id="myform">`
2. `<amp-autocomplete on="select:search-submit">` => `<amp-autocomplete on="change:myform.submit">`

Comment: It works, but the form is submitted only if user types something in the form input. Besides that keywords submitted are only what the user has wrote. Maybe it's like this because the amp-autocomplete was not meant for that…